# Show .NET Framework install progress in Inno Setup

Tags: .net, inno-setup

How can I show the .NET Framework's install progress in a setup created using Inno Setup?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try add the "/passive" to the parameter list of ShellExec or Exec?

I tried, and it worked pretty well.